# $x'(t)=|t-1|x(t)+1,x(0)=0$ Find $x(2)$ (using integrals is possible)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x'(t)=|t-1|x(t)+1,x(0)=0$

Find $x(2)$ (using integrals is possible).

First,how am I suppose to use $x(0)=0$ if I find the solution for $t>1$ and $t<1$ and I have to find $x(2)$ ?

My solution :

Suppose $t>1$.hence $x'(t)=(t-1)x(t)+1$.

By Solving homogeneous ode $x'(t)=(t-1)x(t)\implies x(t)=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}-t+c}$.

Let $x^*(t)=R(t)e^{\frac{t^2}{2}-t}$ be the non-homogeneous solution.

Subtituting $x^*(t)$ in the equation we obtain $R'(t)e^{\frac{t^2}{2}-t}+R(t)(t-1)e^{\frac{t^2}{2}-t}=(t-1)R(t)e^{\frac{t^2}{2}-t}+1$

Here I got stuck.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.